# Hanami validate year less than X

Tags: ruby, validation, hanami

I want to check that a date object I have in a `validator.rb` file has a year field that is less than the year 10000.

```
required(:my_date_object).maybe(
            :date?,
            lt?: '10000-01-01'
          )
```

When running system tests, the following error shows up:

```
ArgumentError:
   comparison of Date with String failed
```

Should I look into converting the date field into a string using `to_s` or something similar and then doing a regexp format check? Or is there a more straightforward way of checking that the date is less than the year 10000?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a `Date` for the `lt?`.

You can write it like follows:

```
required(:my_date_object) { lt?(Date.new(10000, 1, 1)) }
```